# Is there a way for changing different images at different scrolling point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to change one image at a time when I'm scrolling through the page.
This code actually changes all images classes when we get to that point of the scroll.
Is there any other way we can change images individually when scrolling?

Thank you.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var show = $(".show");
    var hide = $(".hide");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 500){
            show.removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
            hide.removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
        } else {
          show.removeClass("hide").addClass('show');
          hide.removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I'll need to see a fiddle or HTML structure. But meanwhile, I'll post a possible solution.

Comment: There's a breakpoint in your code, remember that scroll event fires too often, therefore, your `show` classes are changed to hide, then both the **new** and the **old** `hide` classes are changed back to `show`, then everything becomes `show` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking the scroll position of `window` and `hiding/showing`, this will `hide/show` all elements with the specified class name.

To achieve your purpose, add css `position: relative` to all images (if no `position` is specified already),

Then, iterate through each image as follows...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //var show = $(".show");
    //var hide = $(".hide");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        /*var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 500){
            show.removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
            hide.removeClass('hide').addClass("show");
        } else {
          show.removeClass("hide").addClass('show');
          hide.removeClass('show').addClass("hide");
        }*/
        var images = $('img');//or any other selector
        $.each(images, function () {
            if($(this).offset().top <= -500) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I'm working in a WordPress project with images and classes, there are 3 images and my objective is to when I scroll past for 1st image it changes to the animation, then scroll to the 2nd and the same effect happens, and so on.
I was working with classes but I had the problem above, with this code the images blink but don't actually change. If you need any bit of code to help to understand the structure I can paste here.

Comment: I assume you have some animations defined for your `.hide` and `.show` classes? If that's the case, you'll need to set a timeout before adding the show class to allow the first animation run to the end before starting the second one. If I can see some HTML/CSS then I'll be able to suggest a better solution

Comment: Hey, I have created a pastebin with the code I'm using, hope it helps https://pastebin.com/GfL10t9m . Thanks